# Insert range as variable from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am now searching for a solution longe than i am willing to admin, so here's my problem.

I need to insert a dynamic range of columns cosisting mostly of 2 rows into another sheet after the first column.
I can't hardcode the columns so i made a Application.InputBox where the user has to select the range and then confirms his choice. Now if i take the range and make a msg box with rng.address it shows the range e.G. A$B$.

Now when i try to insert the range i get all kinds of errors depending on the way i try.

My current approach is the following:

```
dim rng as Range
         retry:
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Do that and that", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

 If MsgBox("Your choice " & rng.Address & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
    GoTo continue:
    Else
    GoTo retry:
    End If

         continue:

'#1) i tried this:
Worksheets(templateold).Range(rng).Insert Shift:=xlToRight Worksheets(templatenew).Range(rng)

'#2) and i tried that:
Worksheets(templateold).Range(rng).Copy Worksheets(templatenew).Range(rng)
```

I tried it with selecting fist and then copying too but nothing works. :(

How do i use the range stored in the variable to insert the range in another sheet? Sorrys if my code snippet is bad, i tried more things at work but i don't have everything at home.

Comment: What errors are you getting, where? What is `templateold`?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your source data and your output requirements. Is your worksheet a variable? If not you need quotation marks "templateold". Also, explain your statement, "I can't hardcode the columns",  based on your statements, last column as a variable should work.

Comment: Your statement "a dynamic range of columns cosisting mostly of 2 rows into another sheet after the first column" needs to be more specific.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the source and the target look: https://ibb.co/d7MTA0 .
With dynamic columns i just mean that the next time i'll run the script there may be more of the blue columns which i need to insert in the left picture/templateold. Templateold is the variable for the sheet name of the source and templatenew is the table without blue but where i need to insert it.

Later on i need to match the X from the old table in the blue columns with the new table because some of the cells in column A may have changed or some god added somewhere inbetween. Rows are not necessarily needed.

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to even say how many rows need to get inserted because the desired columns always start at B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will copy the range selected by the user and then insert it into the other sheet in Column B by shifting everything else to the right:

```
Sub foo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim templateold As Worksheet: Set templateold = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim templatenew As Worksheet: Set templatenew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with, amend as required.
Dim rng As Range

retry:
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Do that and that", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

If MsgBox("Your choice " & rng.Address & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
    rng.Copy
    templateold.Range("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Else
    GoTo retry:
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have two sheets, Sheet1 (Copy Source) and Sheet2 (Paste Target).
We know where the data starts (A1 on wsSource), but the data could have 4 columns, or it could have 40 columns (same with rows).

When you are wanting to find the last row or last column in a particular range we use CurrentRegion.Rows/Columns.Count which will return the last row/column as a long.

```
Sub DuplicateRange()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

' We know A1 is the starting (top-left) cell. _
using CurrentRegion.Rows/Columns.Count we can _
find the range of data without hardcoding the columns
lRow = wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
lCol = wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

' Range(A1:lCol,lRow)
With wsSource.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol))
    .Copy wsTarget.Cells(1, 1)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't need to find the last column, the user has to input the column count or the range. I uploaded a picture of my sitation on the comment above.@TylerxYMx