# Insert user defined range into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I set a range and can show it with msg box and rng.address but i can't manage to copy/insert or do aynthing with i. In my code snippet i try to copy it but later on i always need to insert the range after the first column in the other sheet.

Here's one particular problem. I am sure it's very easy or i just misunderstand things.I also don't understand

```
Dim rng As Range


Set rng = Application.InputBox("Please choose a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

 If MsgBox("Your choice " & rng.Address & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
    GoTo continue:
    Else
    GoTo retry:
    End If

continue:


Worksheets("Sheet source").Range(rng).Copy Worksheets("sheet destination").Range("A1").Paste
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `Dim rng As Range` so is already a range in a specific sheet therefore `Range(rng)` doesn't work, because `Range()` awaits an address as parameter (not a range).

Also if you use the `.Copy` syntax in one line (with destination as parameter) you don't need to `.Paste`.

It should be

```
rng.Copy Worksheets("sheet destination").Range("A1")
```

Also using `Goto` (outside an error handing) is a very bad practice. Instead use something like that:

```
Sub AskMe()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Do
        On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if user presses cancel so we hide **all** error messages now (and turn them on later!)
        Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Please choose a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub 'if an error occurred then the user pressed cancel (so we exit)
        On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error reporting! Otherwise all error messages stay hidden.
    Loop Until MsgBox("Your choice " & Rng.Address & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes
    'repeat asking for a range until yes is pressed

    Rng.Copy Worksheets("sheet destination").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you too for clarification, i wasn't aware of that. No surprise that i have so many problems with my main script. (Link in the above comment if you want to look at it)

Comment: @Matthias94 Please have a look at my edit. Using `Goto` is a bad practice. There is a solution without using `Goto` and make it possible for the user to press the cancel button too. • If it solved your issue please mark your desired answer as solution.

Comment: @PeH Thank you very much for you hint, i wrote 3 scripts so far and have no error handling in place which can get ugly and confusing very quickly for the user. I'll follow your advice and practice error handling on my existing scripts :)

One qoestion just to clarify: If i wouldn't turn on error reporting, my script would continue to jump to the next statement following the error causing statement.(I think i can imagine why this would be a bad idea. ) When i get an error on the set statement, the next statement is the if err.number right?

Comment: @Matthias94 Yes if you forget to enable error reporting again with `On Error Goto 0` then all error messages are hidden (you cannot see them) while the errors still occur. So you are blind for all errors, and therefore you cannot find and fix them. That's why it is so important. If you want to learn more about error handling see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling). • yes the next statement is the `if err.number`.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the range you could do it as follows:

```
Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range
retry:
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Please choose a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    If MsgBox("Your choice " & rng.Address & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
        GoTo continue:
    Else
        GoTo retry:
    End If
continue:
rng.Copy 
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I made this mistake on my main problem as well, so maybe i'll manage to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159950

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Matthias94 I've added an answer to your other post, hope it helps! :)